# NHibernate + Npqsql + LINQ gives "Parameter p1 not found in query"

Tags: .net, linq, postgresql, nhibernate, npgsql

I'm converting from MySQL to Postgres, and some linq queries cause exceptions. Specifically, I get a problem on a query that adds a bitwise operator comparison. I noticed that the parameters in the SQL string seem to be positional (?) instead of named (:p1, :p2, :p3).

Any idea why? Here's part of the exception:

select grant0_.\"Id\" as column1_39_, grant0_.\"Version\" as column2_39_, ....
and (grant0_.\"IsPublic\"=TRUE or (grant0_.\"UserId\" is not null) and grant0_.\"UserId\"=?) and grant0_.\"PermissionFlags\"&?=?

Name:p1 - Value:9011
Name:p2 - Value:4
Name:p3 - Value:4

Edit:

I saw this in the NpqsqlCommand.ReplaceParameterValue() function - it might need to contain more operators. I'm experimenting with that.

```
String pattern = "[- |\n\r\t,)(;=+/<>][:|@]" + parameterMarker + parameterName + "([- |\n\r\t,)(;=+/<>]|$)";
```

Answer:
I hope it isn't bad form to answer my own question, but the problem is that the Npgsql driver 2.0.12 does not correctly replace parameters when they follow the '&' symbol. This occurs when you use an integer as a bit field. Below is the Linq:

```
Where(g => (g.flag & flag) == flag)
```

I will submit a patch to the Npgsql team.

Comment: The exception is being thrown from Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ReplaceParameterValue(), so I don't think it is making it to the database.

Comment: In the Npgsql driver in ReplaceParameterValue, I saw this Regex `"[- |\n\r\t,)(;=+/<>][:|@]" + parameterMarker + parameterName + "([- |\n\r\t,)(;=+/<>]|$)"`. Does this need to include the bitwise operator?

Comment: @LogicMan If you find the answer yourself, you should post it as an answer below and then mark it as the accepted answer (there is a few days delay before it will let you).

Comment: ... and another day before it will let you accept your own answer. What a PITA ;-}

Answer (score 1):

I hope it isn't bad form to answer my own question, but the problem is that the Npgsql driver 2.0.12 does not correctly replace parameters when they follow the '&' symbol. This occurs when you use an integer as a bit field. Below is the Linq:

```
Where(g => (g.flag & flag) == flag)
```

I will submit a patch to the Npgsql team.